# Why extension Imagemagick does not work?

Tags: php, centos, imagick

I have installed package `ImageMagick-devel-6.7.2.7-2.el6.x86_64`
Also I have not extension imagemagick in output from `phpinfo()`, but exists row in php.ini:

```
extension="imagick.so"
```

When I try to check via terminal command:

```
php -m |grep imagick
```

I get empty result.

Why I have not enabled extension in phpinfo?

I use Cent OS 6.7, PHP 5.5.22

Comment: You _did_ restart the http server process, didn't you? If so, what does your error log file tell you? I mean there is little sense in _guessing_ what the issue might be if you can simply read what the issue is in your http servers log file.

Comment: Yes, I had restarted, will try to find something in logs

Comment: The package you mentioned above is not a PHP extension, it's just ImageMagick. You need to install the ImageMagick PHP extension too. Try `pecl install imagick`

Comment: pecl/imagick is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.2